# C Programming: How to read input byte at a time and output only integers as tokens?

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I have to write a program that picks up only the integers from the standard input and output them as tokens.  Anything else should be outputted as "illegal".  I'm **not permitted** to use any arrays or malloc, and I could only declare ints or long ints.  I **must use getchar() for input and printf() for output** and nothing else.  My question is, how do I read input byte at a time, convert them to tokens and check if they are ints?

For example: If the input is:

```
Hello 45 World Thank 67 you
```

It should output:

```
illegal
45
illegal
illegal
67
illegal
```

Comment: Hate to ask, but didn't the teacher provide _any_ instructions as to how you should perform I/O in C? Or did they just throw you the assignment to see if you're handy on the internet?

Comment: What should happen if the input integer is _too long_ to be a valid integer in the language description? Say, `12345678901234567890`...

Comment: I have to ask, what have you tried and/or what have you thought of doing so far?

Comment: @sarnold - Actually it should print overflow, but I left that part out for now just because I wanted to get started on this somewhere somehow.

Comment: what happens if the input is:Hello 4+5 world

Comment: @shengy - It should print 4 and 5 in two desperate lines (it shouldn't add up, the + sign is taken as plus 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int ch;
    int n;
    int takeNum, sign;
    long long int wk;//long long int as int64

    wk=0LL;
    takeNum = 0;//flag
    sign = 1;//minus:-1, other:1
    while(EOF!=(ch=getchar())){
        if(ch == '-'){
            sign = -1;
            continue;
        }
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
            if(takeNum >= 0)
                takeNum = 1;
            else
                continue;
            wk = wk * 10 + (ch - '0')*sign;
            if(INT_MAX < wk || INT_MIN > wk){//overflow
                takeNum = -1;//for skip
            }
            continue;
        }
        //space character continuing is "illegal"
        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n'){
            if(takeNum <= 0)
                printf("illegal\n");
            else
                printf("%d\n", n=wk);
            wk=0LL; takeNum=0; sign=1;//reset
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inspection is still not enough.

Comment: @SharkTiles - There are many flaws in this program, because  I made as a prototype only.

Comment: your answer pointed me in the right direction.  The key to the answer is to design a state machine, which accepts input 1 character at a time and see if it leads to an accepting state.

Answer (score 2):

Because this is for homework (thanks for labeling it clearly), I'll give a sketch in pseudo-code that will hopefully put you on the correct track.

Your program doesn't actually *care* about tokenizing, as such; it just needs to print the correct output for the given input.

So, something like this:

```
int ch; /* note _int_, not _char_ -- this will save you time debugging */

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)  /* idiomatic read-a-char loop */
    if ch == '0' or ch == '1' or ..
        print ch
        already_seen_invalid = 0
    else
        if already_seen_invalid == 0
            already_seen_invalid = 1
            print invalid
```

The `already_seen_invalid` toggle will only give you one `invalid` output regardless of how many bytes are invalid.

Don't worry about trying to turn the bytes `'4'` and `'5'` into an integer `45`. Your program doesn't care and it won't help you to care either.

Comment: Ah, I see now that you're interested in doing the `overflow` route if the numbers are too large... hopefully this will _still_ be enough of a starting point for you to figure that last bit out. :)